# Unable to build dojo 1.9.3

Tags: dojo

I am using this command to build dojo 1.9.3

"**ant -file buildWAR.xml -DbuildWorkDir=G:\Codebase\folder\PSInviter -DzuoraJarFile=WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\zuora.jar"**

but in reponse of this I am getting the following error:

```
[exec] G:\Codebase\folder\PSInviter\WebContent\js\dojo-release-1.9.3-src\util\ buildscripts>java -Xms256m -Xmx256m  -cp    "           G:\Codebase\folder\PSInviter\WebContent\js\dojo-release-1.9.3-src\uti
l\buildscripts\../shrinksafe/js.jar";"G:\Codebase\folder\
PSInviter\WebContent\js\dojo-release-1.9.3-src\util\buildscripts\../closureCompi
ler/compiler.jar";"G:\Codebase\folder\PSInviter\WebConten
t\js\dojo-release-1.9.3-src\util\buildscripts\../shrinksafe/shrinksafe.jar" org.
mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main  "G:\Codebase\folder\
PSInviter\WebContent\js\dojo-release-1.9.3-src\util\buildscripts\../../dojo/dojo
.js" baseUrl="G:\Codebase\folder\PSInviter\WebContent\js\
dojo-release-1.9.3-src\util\buildscripts\../../dojo" load=build      releaseDir=G:\Codebase\folder\PSInviter\WebContent\js\builds/ profileFile
=G:\Codebase\folder\PSInviter/WebContent/js/somefolder
/timedriver.profile.js copyTests=false action=clean,release optimize=shrinksafe
localeList=ar,ca,cs,da,de,de-de,el,en,en-au,en-ca,en-gb,en-us,es,es-es,fi,fr,he,
hu,it,it-it,ja,ja-jp,ko,ko-kr,nb,nl,pl,pt,pt-br,ru,sk,sl,sv,th,tr,zh,zh-cn,zh-tw
releaseName=1405191028 internStrings=true cssOptimize=comments excludeFromBase=
true
[exec] org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: g
```

below is my buildWar.xml file's code

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

   <!-- Build the PSInviter WAR project -->
   <project name="PSInviter.WAR" basedir="." default="default">

   <!-- All properties are in build.properties -->
   <property environment="env" /> 
   <property file="buildWAR.properties" />
   <property name="dojoSrcRelease" location="WebContent/js/dojo-release-1.9.3-src" />
   <property name="outputDir" location="WebContent/js/builds" />

   <path id="compile.classpath">
    <pathelement path="${classes.dir}" />
    <fileset dir="${was.api.dir}" includes="runtimes/websphere_apis.jar" />
    <fileset dir="${was.api.dir}" includes="java/jre/lib/**/*.jar" />
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
   </path>

   <target name="init" description="Initialize the build process">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}/js/builds"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}/js/builds"/>
    <delete dir="${outputDir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${outputDir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${temp.artifacts.dir}"/>
    <tstamp>
        <format property="buildDateTime" pattern="yyMMddHHmm"/>
    </tstamp>
   </target>

   <target name="build-dojo" description="" depends="init">

        <exec dir="${dojoSrcRelease}/util/buildscripts/" executable="${dojoSrcRelease}/util/buildscripts/build.bat">
            <arg line="releaseDir=&quot;${outputDir}/&quot;"/>
            <arg line="profileFile=&quot;${basedir}/WebContent/js/someFolder/timedriver.profile.js&quot;"/>
            <arg line="copyTests=false"/>
            <arg line="action=clean,release"/>
            <arg line="optimize=shrinksafe"/>
            <arg line="localeList=ar,ca,cs,da,de,de-de,el,en,en-au,en-ca,en-gb,en-us,es,es-es,fi,fr,he,hu,it,it-it,ja,ja-jp,ko,ko-kr,nb,nl,pl,pt,pt-br,ru,sk,sl,sv,th,tr,zh,zh-cn,zh-tw"/>
            <arg line="releaseName=${buildDateTime}" />
            <arg line="internStrings=true" />
            <arg line="cssOptimize=comments" />
            <arg line="excludeFromBase=true" />

        </exec>

        <replaceregexp file="${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/startup.properties"
                         match="TDBuildNumber=(.*)"
                         replace="TDBuildNumber=${buildDateTime}"
                         byline="true"/>

        <java dir="WebContent/js" classname="org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main" fork="true">
            <arg value="nonDojo/nonDojoBuilder.js"/>
            <arg value="nonDojo/base.js|nonDojo/login.js|nonDojo/securityPolicy.js|nonDojo/MD5.js|jsonrpc.js|nonDojo/loginpage.js"/>
            <arg value="${outputDir}/${buildDateTime}/loginPage.js"/>
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${exec.dir}/../WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/js.jar"/>
                <pathelement location="${exec.dir}/../WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/shrinksafe.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </java>

        <java dir="WebContent/js" classname="org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main" fork="true">
            <arg value="nonDojo/nonDojoBuilder.js"/>
            <arg value="nonDojo/base.js|nonDojo/login.js|nonDojo/sfdclanding.js|nonDojo/securityPolicy.js|nonDojo/MD5.js|jsonrpc.js|nonDojo/registration.js"/>
            <arg value="${outputDir}/${buildDateTime}/sfdclandingPage.js"/>
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${exec.dir}/../WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/js.jar"/>
                <pathelement location="${exec.dir}/../WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/shrinksafe.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </java>

        <copy file="${basedir}/WebContent/js/jsonrpc.js" todir="${outputDir}/${buildDateTime}" />
        <copy file="${basedir}/WebContent/js/nonDojo/securityPolicy.js" todir="${outputDir}/${buildDateTime}" />

    </target>

  <target name="copy-files" depends="build-dojo" description="Copy the web content files">
    <copy todir="${build.dir}">
      <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
        <exclude name="**/.svn"/>
        <exclude name="**/js/dojo*/**"/>
        <exclude name="**/js/someFolder/**"/>
      </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${build.dir}/AST" failonerror="true">
          <fileset dir="AST">
            <exclude name="**/.svn"/>
          </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${build.dir}/WEB-INF/lib" failonerror="true" file="${zuoraJarFile}" overwrite="true" />
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="copy-files" description="Compile the Java source code">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}"
           destdir="${classes.dir}"
           includes="**/*.java"
           classpathref="compile.classpath"
           source="${javac.source}"
           target="${javac.target}"
           debug="${javac.debug}"
           fork="true"
           includeAntRuntime="no"
    />  
  </target>

  <target name="war" depends="compile" description="Create the WAR file">
    <manifest file="MANIFEST.MF">
        <attribute name="Build-Version" value="${buildVersion} - ${buildDateTime}"/>
    </manifest>
    <delete dir="${build.dir}/AST"/>
    <mkdir dir="target"/>
    <war destfile="target/${war.file}" 
         webxml="${web-inf.dir}/web.xml"
         basedir="${build.dir}"
         manifest="MANIFEST.MF"
    />
    <copy todir="${temp.artifacts.dir}" failonerror="true">
          <fileset dir="target">
            <exclude name="**/.svn"/>
            <include name="${war.file}"/>
          </fileset>
    </copy>
  </target> 


  <target name="jar" depends="compile" description="Create the timedriver jar file">
    <jar destfile="target/${jar.file}"
       basedir="${classes.dir}"
    />
    <copy todir="${temp.artifacts.dir}" overwrite="true" failonerror="true">
          <fileset dir="target">
            <exclude name="**/.svn"/>
            <include name="${jar.file}"/>
          </fileset>
    </copy>
  </target> 

  <target name="default" depends="war, jar" />

</project>
```

Anyone know about this error, please help.

Regards

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but you have a combination of `/` and `\` in your file paths, which might be worth fixing.

Comment: I compile this with dojo1.3.1, then this works fine but but when I compile with dojo1.9.3 it does not work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was experiencing a similar problem and after some investigation I realize that the problem was that I have ignored a couple of directories required to create the dojo build.

In my particular case the issue was related to ignoring (deleted) the util/build directory of the sdk.

You can debug this by adding:

```
console.log(url);
```

At [dojo/_base/configRhino.js](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/_base/configRhino.js#L62) on the isLocal function.

This function determines if a file is local or a URL and if the file does not exists then it assumes that is a URL and then the exception occur.

That extra line is going to print all the files that is trying to use and when it breaks the last file path that printed is the faulty one.

All of this of course is just a guess based on my experience.

Comment: thanks for reply, I had resolved this issue, I also had the same problem, i.e. missing the util/build folder, but thanks for your reply :)